# Entrez eFetch Accession Number

Tags: python, bioinformatics, biopython, ncbi

We are currently working on a project where we need to access the 'NP_' accession number from ClinVar. However, when we use the Entrez.eFetch( ) function, this information appears to be missing in the result. Here is a link to the website page where the NP_ number is listed:

https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/clinvar/variation/558834/

And here is the Python sample script code that fetches the XML result:

```
handle = Entrez.efetch(db="clinvar", id=558834, rettype='variation', retmode="text")
print(handle.read())
```

Interestingly enough, this *used* to return the NP number in the results, however, it seems to the website formatting/style changed from when we last developed our Python script and we cannot seem to figure out how to retrieve the NP number now.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you for your time and input!

Answer (score 0):

You need to format it like a [new query](https://eutils.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/entrez/eutils/efetch.fcgi?db=clinvar&rettype=vcv&is_variationid&id=558834&from_esearch=true) not an [old one](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/entrez/eutils/efetch.fcgi?db=clinvar&rettype=variation&id=558834):

```
handle = Entrez.efetch(db="clinvar", id=558834, rettype='vcv', is_varationid="true", from_esearch="true")
print(handle.read())
```

See also: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/clinvar/docs/maintenance_use/

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! I will be sure to bookmark this reference!